# Rails 3. Kaminari displays pagination links but doesn't change the records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, kaminari

I'm using Rails 3, ActiveAdmin and Kaminari.

I have this on the documents.rb file (activeadmin file).

```
collection_action :index do
  @page_title = "Documents"
  @shipments = Shipment.page(params[:id]).per(3)
  render '_invoices', :layout => 'active_admin'
end
```

The pagination links are displayed fine. I click the pagination links and I do get this in the URL `http://localhost:3000/admin/documents?page=4` so it seems fine. The problem is, it always displays the same records, they don't change according to the page.

This is what I have as the partial that is being rendered...

```
<table class="index_table">
  <tr>
    <th>File #</th>
    ... buncla th's
  </tr>
<% @shipments.each do |shipment| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even") %>">
    <td><%= link_to shipment.file_number, admin_shipment_path(shipment) %></td>
    ...buncha cells...
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<div id="index_footer"><%= paginate @shipments %></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the page parameter and not id.

`@shipments = Shipment.page(params[:page]).per(3)`